# Spark SQL 2.0: NullPointerException with a valid PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a valid PostgreSQL query : when I copy/paste it in PSQL, I get the desired result.
But when I run with Spark SQL it leads to a `NullPointerException`.

Here is the snippet of code causing the error:

```
extractDataFrame().show()

private def extractDataFrame(): DataFrame = {
  val query =
    """(
      SELECT events.event_facebook_id, events.name, events.tariffrange,
        eventscounts.attending_count, eventscounts.declined_count, eventscounts.interested_count,
        eventscounts.noreply_count,
        artists.facebookid as artist_facebook_id, artists.likes as artistlikes,
        organizers.organizerid, organizers.likes as organizerlikes,
        places.placeid, places.capacity, places.likes as placelikes
      FROM events
        LEFT JOIN eventscounts on eventscounts.event_facebook_id = events.event_facebook_id
        LEFT JOIN eventsartists on eventsartists.event_id = events.event_facebook_id
          LEFT JOIN artists on eventsartists.artistid = artists.facebookid
        LEFT JOIN eventsorganizers on eventsorganizers.event_id = events.event_facebook_id
          LEFT JOIN organizers on eventsorganizers.organizerurl = organizers.facebookurl
        LEFT JOIN eventsplaces on eventsplaces.event_id = events.event_facebook_id
          LEFT JOIN places on eventsplaces.placefacebookurl = places.facebookurl
      ) df"""

  spark.sqlContext.read.jdbc(databaseURL, query, connectionProperties)
}
```

The SparkSession is defined as follows:

```
val databaseURL = "jdbc:postgresql://dbHost:5432/ticketapp" 
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("tariffPrediction")
  .getOrCreate()

val connectionProperties = new Properties
connectionProperties.put("user", "simon")
connectionProperties.put("password", "root")
```

And here is the complete stacktrace:

```
[SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 27.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 27.0 (TID 27, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter.write(UnsafeRowWriter.java:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:]
```

The most surprising part is that if I remove one (whichever one) of the `LEFT JOIN` clauses in the SQL query, I don't get any errors...

Answer (score 8):

I have a very similar issues instead with a Teradata data source, and it came down to the column nullability on the DataFrame did not match the underlying data (the column had nullable=false, but some rows had null values in that particular field).  The cause in my case was the Teradata JDBC Driver not returning the correct column metadata.  I am yet to find a workaround to this.

To see the code that is being generated (within which the NPE is being thrown):

- import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.debug._
- call .debugCodegen() on the DataSet/DataFrame

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to Teradata JDBC driver. This problem is discussed at https://community.teradata.com/t5/Connectivity/Teradata-JDBC-Driver-returns-the-wrong-schema-column-nullability/m-p/76667/highlight/true#M3798.

The root cause is discussed on the first page. And the solution is on the third page.

People from Teradata said they fixed the issue in the 16.10.* driver with a MAYBENULL parameter, but I am still seeing an undeterministic behaviour.

Here is a similar discussion https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17195

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is still looking for a solution, you can use `NULLIF` on the column that is causing problems, caused by a `JOIN` resulting in a null value for a column that was originally `not null` in the specified schema.

Related JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18859