# In Spark 2.0, jdbc dataframes schema is automatically applied as nullable = false

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

For jdbc dataframes if I specify a custom query like

```
(select * from table1 where col4 > 10.0) AS table1
```

then schema for all columns turns out to be nullable = false

```
col1: string (nullable = false)
col2: string (nullable = false)
col3: string (nullable = false)
col4: float (nullable = false)
```

This causes null pointer exception when I use custom queries and the resultset contains any null value. I also tried to transform schema programatically but it still fails because of spark lineage, as original dataframe has the restricted schema irrespective of what schema transformed dataframe has.

I found a workaround for this. If I just provide the table name and then provide the select and where clause

`sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, table1, dconnectionProperties).
              select("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4").
              where(s"col4 < 10.0")`

the schema is correctly(or I how I want) inferred as

```
col1: string (nullable = true)
col2: string (nullable = true)
col3: string (nullable = true)
col4: float (nullable = true)
```

But I wanted to use the custom queries as my queries has some join and aggregations which I want to be pushed down to database to execute.

This started showing up after we moved to spark 2.0.x prior to that this was working fine

Comment: This is reproducible on latest teradata jdbc driver 16.00.00.23, and it might not just be with teradata, found another post having similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875711/spark-sql-2-0-nullpointerexception-with-a-valid-postgresql-query

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to Teradata JDBC driver. This problem is discussed at https://community.teradata.com/t5/Connectivity/Teradata-JDBC-Driver-returns-the-wrong-schema-column-nullability/m-p/76667/highlight/true#M3798.

The root cause is discussed on the first page. And the solution is on the third page.

People from Teradata said they fixed the issue in the 16.10.* driver with a MAYBENULL parameter, but I am still seeing an undeterministic behaviour.

Here is a similar discussion
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17195

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop, this issue is fixed in driver version `16.04.00.0`. Two new parameters need to be added in the connection string `COLUMN_NAME=ON,MAYBENULL=ON`